# How to find out when MySQL connection is secured or not when using SslMode = Preferred

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ssl, database-connection

I have a client application written in VB.NET which connecting to a remote MySQL server.
I'd like to sign on the UI when the connection is secure or insecure.

`SslMode` is set to `Preferred` (use SSL if the server supports it, but allow connection in all cases)

**Once mysql connection established, how can I decide is it a secured connection or not?**

Here is how my connection string looks like:

```
'Declaring the MySqlConnection
_MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection( _
               New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder() _
               With { _
                 .Port = port, _
                 .Server = server, _ 
                 .UserID = username, _ 
                 .Password = password, _ 
                 .Database = database, _
                 .SslMode = MySqlSslMode.Preferred _
               }.ConnectionString
             )
```

I'm using mysql.data (6.5.4.0) if it is matters.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-ssl-connections.html

> A client can determine whether the current connection with the server uses SSL by checking the value of the `Ssl_cipher` status variable. The value of `Ssl_cipher` is nonempty if SSL is used, and empty otherwise. For example:

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';
+---------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name | Value              |
+---------------+--------------------+
| Ssl_cipher    | DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA |
+---------------+--------------------+
```

Issue this command just like any regular query, and parse its result like a regular result set.

Comment: the link is broken and it returns the same result with and without TLS